# Spotlight has quit unexpectedly

Tags: xcode, crash, spotlight, xcode-simulator

I am running a flutter application build from the command line. I also have an ios simulator running.

I keep getting an error saying "spotlight has quit unexpectedly". Has anyone seen this issue before?

```
Process:               Spotlight [93380]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications/Spotlight.app/Spotlight
Identifier:            Spotlight
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [93247]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [93237]
User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2020-12-07 13:17:20.865 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        7314686F-26C9-E59B-2317-7F5D00F51293

Sleep/Wake UUID:       8C755EE1-CA06-41A4-A036-2AE52E46A9EE

Time Awake Since Boot: 1200000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
```

Answer (score 2):

The path shown in the crash log is within Xcode, specifically the iPhoneOS.platform iOS.simruntime. **This Spotlight is the one running in the simulator**, not the one in macOS. **This is not a ‘real’ issue** and can safely be ignored unless you’re testing Spotlight functionality within the app you’re running in the simulator.

This is a commonly reported issue, especially since Xcode 12. Solutions posted elsewhere that may or may not work include

- [Disabling Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Look Up on the simulator Settings app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64240553/1549818)
- [Adding CoreSimulator to Spotlight privacy](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660734?answerId=645964022#645964022)

To make crash reports show as a notification first to avoid interrupting your work, set the following preference:

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType UseUNC 1
```

Comment: Lol it cannot be safely ignored when an error dialog repeatedly pops up every 3 seconds. What a garbage answer.

Comment: @ScottF It should only be a notification in the corner, I have added the Terminal command to set that preference. Did the mentioned possible solutions not work for you?

Comment: No its a giant almost fullscreen error dialog that pops up every 5 seconds roughly, not a notification in the corner.

Comment: @Scorb But did you try the command in the answer to change the dialog to a notification?